# How can I reset the position of my player when touching a certain layer in unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to reset the position of my player (to 0, 2, 0) when I touch the layer Death". How can I do this?

I have tried using a `bool` called `isDead`, my code looks something like this:

```
if(isDead)
{
   transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 2f,0f);
}
```

This is the entirety of my code, might help

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;

    public float gravity = -9.81f;

scripts
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    bool isDead;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);


for evig når den treffer bakken
        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

            float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what to do. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can add a collider component to your player, for example a box or capsule collider. Reference it in your script and then use the `onTriggerEnter(Collider collider)` method. You can then set the position in there. Here is the documentation regarding the `onTriggerEnter(Collider collider)` method. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html.

Also here is a video with a similar use case to what you are doing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoZcBgRR9ns. Note that the video is making a 2d game but the same would apply to 3d but without the '2D'.

Something unrelated to your question but thought it would help is Unity's new input system. The `float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");` and `float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");` are quite old and the new input system is much better and easier. I'd suggest you look into it. One more thing, it is recommended to do any physics check in the `FixedUpdate` method rather than the `Update()` method. That would be the check to see if you collided (`isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);`) and setting the velocity and moving the player as well. You would also need to change the `Time.deltaTime` to `Time.fixedDeltaTime` anywhere you use it in the `FixedUpdate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If the Colliders on the death-layer are triggers, you need [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html), otherwise [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html). Example:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 2f, 0f);
}
```

Comment: what  should i specify as collisions?

Comment: You add GameObjects with Colliders on your Death Layer. Does not matter if it's Box, Sphere or Capsule collider etc.